# Group repeating pattern in pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, grouping

so i have a Dataframe that has a repeating Number Series that i want to group like this:

| Number Pattern | Value | Desired Group | Value.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 723 | 1 | Max of Group |
| 2 | 400 | 1 | Max of Group |
| 8 | 235 | 1 | Max of Group |
| 5 | 387 | 2 | Max of Group |
| 7 | 911 | 2 | Max of Group |
| 3 | 365 | 3 | Max of Group |
| 4 | 270 | 3 | Max of Group |
| 5 | 194 | 3 | Max of Group |
| 7 | 452 | 3 | Max of Group |
| 100 | 716 | 4 | Max of Group |
| 104 | 69 | 4 | Max of Group |
| 2 | 846 | 5 | Max of Group |
| 3 | 474 | 5 | Max of Group |
| 4 | 524 | 5 | Max of Group |

So essentially the number pattern is always monotonly increasing.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Last value is `Desired Group` should be `5` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes right! thx

Comment: Some problem with my solution?

Comment: Hey @jezrael, I commented on the problem with the Solution. It was actually my fault, since the problem is a bit more tricky. If you dont have an idea for the edited problem, i can reset it to the original, and mark your answer as correct again, so your effort wasnt for nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare `Number Pattern` by `1` with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then is used [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `max`:

```
df['Desired Group'] = df['Number Pattern'].eq(1).cumsum()
df['Value.1'] = df.groupby('Desired Group')['Value'].transform('max')
print (df)
    Number Pattern  Value  Desired Group  Value.1
0                1    723              1      723
1                2    400              1      723
2                3    235              1      723
3                1    387              2      911
4                2    911              2      911
5                1    365              3      452
6                2    270              3      452
7                3    194              3      452
8                4    452              3      452
9                1    716              4      716
10               2     69              4      716
11               1    846              5      846
12               2    474              5      846
13               3    524              5      846
```

For monotically increasing use:

```
df['Desired Group'] = (~df['Number Pattern'].diff().gt(0)).cumsum()
```

Comment: hey,
so i went through the data and realized that the number pattern is actually a bit more tricky. I will update the Question in this regard.
So agian, if you have any ideas i would be glad to hear :)

Comment: @leMiro - Answer was edited.